# What is the difference between vi and vim?

Tags: vim, vi

As far as I know `vi` is more commonly found on out-of-the-box unix systems while `vim` often has to be installed. Also `vim` stands for `vi improved`, but improved how?

What are the main differences?

Comment: Be aware that in many systems, "vi" is just a symbolic link to "vim".

Comment: And what happens where is not?

For example, in my Fedora 20, i have /usr/bin/vi and /usr/bin/vim, none is a symbolic link, but when i run vim i have this:


"VIM - VI Mejorado
versión 7.4.475"


When i run vi:


"VIM - Vi IMproved
version 7.4.475"


Seem like a link, but vi don't read the .vimrc, i tried creating a .virc, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check your aliases
Type 'alias' and run that,
Do you see vi=vim
If that is the case, this may be why.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Vim tries to resemble the syntax and semantic of Vi command as much as possible. But being an "improved version", Vim adds new commands and features. It also changes the semantic of some Vi commands to better match the current expectations of its programmers.

A detailed list of changes between vim and Vi can be found using the command `:help compatible` in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Vim is an advanced text editor that seeks to provide the power of the de-facto Unix editor 'Vi', with a more complete feature set. It's useful whether you're [already using vi](http://vim.sourceforge.net/viusers.php) or [using a different editor](http://vim.sourceforge.net/others.php).

---

Source: http://vim.sourceforge.net/about.php