# How to do vi edit on bash Linux?

Tags: bash, vim

Almost 5 years ago, used to do something like VIEDIT (forgot exact word I used to use).

Usecase - when I want paste bunch of lines of program or strings I do something like viedit (again I forgot the exact name) and paste over there, instead of all mess it looks clean excited what I mention on that editor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between vi and vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30465/what-is-the-difference-between-vi-and-vim)

Comment: @jesse_b it is not, unfortunately I am not looking for diff on vi and vim. It is something diff altogether..

Comment: You are looking for `vi`/`vim`.  There are literally thousands of questions/answers about them on here that will answer your question.  That was the most generic one I could find.  You could also just google "how do I edit a file on linux" and you will surely find guides on vim/nano

Comment: If you just want to paste something into a fresh file, do `cat >filename` then paste, then press `Ctrl+D` when done.

Comment: Or if you have `xsel` you can: `xsel --clipboard --output >filename`

Comment: Thank you @Jesse_b , It is completly my mistake on not explaining properly .

Still , I am not looking for vi or vim . Basically on the bash shell , if we have bunch of script to execute without writting to a file , we can use something like viedit ( which need to set ) , that piece I am missing.

Comment: "if we have bunch of script to execute without writting to a file" Nothing needs to be done if you don't want to write to a file.  Can you try to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/513574/edit) your question with a detailed explanation of exactly what you are trying to do?  As is, what you are asking is how to: open `vi`, press `i` (to enter insert mode), and press `ctrl`+`z` to paste text

Comment: I tried an answer, but if your looking just for using `vi` bindings in the command line, `set -o vi` (or `set editing-mode vi` in `.inputrc` with `bash` and other programs that use the `readline` library) may do. eg. enter `HELLO`, press `Esc`, and `|` to go to the beginning of the line, and then press and keep pressed `~` to turn into `hello`, just like in the command mode of `vi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you, but you may be looking for the [`fc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/fc.html) shell builtin.

```
FCEDIT=vi
fc
```

will let you edit in `vi` your last command line.

Comment: Yes , Yes , Yes.. 

this is what I am looking for .. 

Thank you so much @mosvy for understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure this question is about vim. However if you do
Cx-Ce (which is hold control then press x and press e)
it will open an editor where you can copy paste your code. 
The code will be executed after you save and close editor.

The editor is configurable and it could be vim.